# Symfony - Restrict registration from specific domain

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-validator

I am working on a registration form where I need to put a validation on email id, if the email domain does not belong to a specific domain then person should not be able to register so my question is does symfony by default has this validation option which I can turn on or i need to create a custom validation?

For example I only want people to register if the email id has `yahoo.com`

Comment: Consider edit the question, you are talking about email's domain, the is no such thing as "email id"

Comment: @MarianoArgañaraz thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's not a build-in feature in symfony2 for check domain email. But you can add it. What you can do is [creating a custom constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html).

```
namespace AppBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class EmailDomain extends Constraint
{
    public $domains;
    public $message = 'The email "%email%" has not a valid domain.';
}
```

```
namespace AppBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class EmailDomainValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $explodedEmail = explode('@', $value);
        $domain = array_pop($explodedEmail);

        if (!in_array($domain, $constraint->domains)) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                 ->setParameter('%email%', $value)
                 ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

After that you can use the new validator:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use AppBundle\Validator\Constraints as CustomAssert;

class MyEntity
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Email()
     * @CustomAssert\EmailDomain(domains = {"yahoo.com", "gmail.com"})
     */
    protected $email;
```

In case someone needs to add the validation inside the `.yml` file here is how you can do it.

```
    - AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\EmailDomain:
        domains:
            - yahoo.com
```

Comment: Thanks, I am looking into this and will get back

Comment: how can i add this validation inside a `.yml` file as I am not using annotation for validation

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Regex constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/reference/constraints/Regex.html) to test email address for several email domains. In other case you will have to create your own constraint.

Comment: can you give me an example on how Regex constraint can be used for this purpose?

Comment: You can try something like ^[a-zA-Z]+@(domain1\.com|domain2\.com|etc)$