# Symfony formbuilder: validate email domain?

Tags: forms, symfony, validation, email, formbuilder

it's possible on a email filed (form builder) to restric some domains like "@gmail.com"?

I want to acept only some email in registration form.

Comment: What have you tried? Let's see your code please

Comment: I have not tried anything yet. I Want to set up in the formbuilder some that the user only can imput "myname@XXXX.XXX" -> the "@XXXX.XXX".

            $builder->add('email', EmailType::class, array(
                'constraints' => array(
                    new NotBlank(array(
                        'message' => 'textextext',
                        'groups' => array(self::VALIDATION_GROUP),
                    ))
            ));

Comment: So what did you do?

Answer (score 1):

You can first play with Symfony EmailValidator:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Email.html

Or you can use something like that, playing with custom constraint:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36452969/8526318

Answer (score 1):

Finally I haved tried to create a custom constrain validator like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36452969/8526318

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible. Try use [Validation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html).